# Rotating Problems

Tags: javascript

I cannot get this to rotate 90 degrees:

The question is : **write a function named rotateArt that takes two (2) parameters: `imageArray` and `rotation`.**

- `imageArray` is a 2D array of any dimension containing an ASCII art “image.”
- `rotation` is a value that is one of the following values: `0`, `90`, `180`, `270`, `360`, `-90`, `-180`, `-270`.

A positive value indicates a rotation in the clockwise direction. A negative value indicates a rotation in the counter-clockwise direction. A value of `0` or `360` means that no rotation is to take place, but that the image is to be mirrored or flipped around the vertical axis.

```js
function rotateChar(char, rotation) {
    let rowLookup = ['^', 'v', '>', '<', '|', '-', '|', '\\', '/', '`', '~', '[', '=', '_'];
    let colLookup = [-270, -180, -90, 0, 90, 180, 270];
    let rotations = [
        ['>', 'v', '<', '^', '>', 'v', '<'],
        ['<', '^', '>', 'v', '<', '^', '>'],
        ['v', '<', '^', '>', 'v', '<', '^'],
        ['^', '>', 'v', '<', '^', '>', 'v'],
        ['-', '|', '-', '|', '-', '|', '-'],
        ['|', '-', '|', '-', '|', '-', '|'],
        ['_', '|', '_', '|', '_', '|', '_'],
        ['/', '\\', '/', '\\', '/', '\\', '/'],
        ['\\', '/', '\\', '/', '\\', '/', '\\'],
        ['`', '~', '`', '~', '`', '~', '`'],
        ['~', '`', '~', '`', '~', '`', '~'],
        ['=', '[', '=', '[', '=', '[', '='],
        ['[', '=', '[', '=', '[', '=', '['],
    ];

    if (rowLookup.indexOf(char) === -1 || colLookup.indexOf(rotation) === -1) {
        return char;
    } else {
        return rotations[rowLookup.indexOf(char)][colLookup.indexOf(rotation)];
    }
}

function rotateArt(imageArray, rotation) {
    //make sure rotation is an int
    rotation = parseInt(rotation);

    //create a new array to store our values in
    let newArray = [];

    switch (rotation) {
        case 90:
        case -270: //CLOCKWISE ROTATION OF 90deg

            //start at left column going to the right
            for (let j = 0; j < imageArray[0].length; j++) {

                //create new row
                let newRow = [];

                //go bottom up and append value to row
                for (let i = imageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    newRow.push(imageArray[i][j]);
                }

                //add the row to the newArray
                newArray.push(newRow);
            }

            break;

            //180 and -180 are the same
        case 180:
        case -180:

            //go bottom up
            for (let i = imageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                //create new row
                let newRow = [];

                //go right to left
                for (let j = imageArray[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    newRow.push(imageArray[i][j]);
                }

                //add the row to the newArray
                newArray.push(newRow);
            }
            break;

            //-90 and 270 are the same
        case -90:
        case 270:


            //go bottom up on columns
            for (let j = imageArray[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                //create new row
                let newRow = [];

                //go left to right on rows
                for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
                    newRow.push(imageArray[i][j]);
                }
                //add the row to the newArray
                newArray.push(newRow);
            }
            break;

            //0 and 360 are the same
        case 0:
        case 360: //flip on vertical axes

            //refill the array from bottom to top
            for (let i = imageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                let newRow = [];

                //add the columns in the same order
                for (let j = 0; j < imageArray[i].length; j++) {
                    newRow.push(imageArray[i][j]);
                }

                //add the row to the newArray
                newArray.push(newRow);
            }
            //break from this case
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
    return newArray;
}

let art1 = [
    ['.', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '.'],
['|', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '|'],
['|', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '|'],
['|', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '|'],
['|', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '|'],
['|', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '|'],
['|', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '|'],
['|', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '|'],
['|', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '/', '/', '\\', '\\', '|'],
['\'', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '\'']
];

console.log(art1)
console.log(rotateArt(art1, 90));

In the example below, the original array is rotated 90 degrees clockwise using the function
call rotateArt(origArray, 90). origArray would be the input array into the function and
90 indicates a clockwise rotation of 90 degrees
ORIGINAL ARRAY ARRAY 
.----------------------------.
|\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//| 
|//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\| 
|\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//| 
|//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\| 
|\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//| 
|//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\| 
|\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//| 
|//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\|
’----------------------------’

Answer would be:

~--------.
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/|
|\/\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\|
~--------.
```

Comment: Is it possible to add some sample input and a corresponding output?

Comment: I ran your code on the 'simple' object and it did rotate 90 degrees, so what's the input which is not rotating to 90 degrees ?

Comment: The art1 part is the par that it is not rotating.